CVXPY expression not DCP?
I have three variables
m = cp.Variable(1, pos=True)
n = cp.Variable(1, pos=True)

soc = cp.Variable(T, pos=True)

t_step = 0.3333
ch_eff = 0.99
E_bt = m * 100

and I'm adding constraints
constraints = []
constraints += [soc<=0.9]
constraints += [soc>=0.1]
constraints += [soc[0] == 0.4]

# Recursive relationship
for t in range(1, T):
 constraints += [soc[t] == soc[t-1]+(((n*p_pv[t-1]-p_load[t-1])*t_step*ch_eff)/E_bt)]


The problem to solve
cost_pv = 100000 #$
cost_battery = 50000 #$
objective = cp.Minimize(m * cost_battery + n * cost_pv)
prob = cp.Problem(objective, constraints)
prob.solve()


p_pv and p_load are lists of float value.
Why does this give me an error?
The following constraints are not DCP:
var627905[1] == var627905[0] + (var627904 @ 0.0 + -0.0) @ 0.333333333 @ 0.9 / var627903 @ 100.0 , because the following subexpressions are not:
|--  (var627904 @ 0.0 + -0.0) @ 0.333333333 @ 0.9 / var627903 @ 100.0

and how do I check this here if the problem is DCP or not?
I have tried different constraints and variable settings in cvxpy but I am not sure why this is the error I get.

You are essentially trying to take a quotient of two variables. That is not DCP. Since it looks like it is always going to be the same quotient n/m maybe you can reformulate the problem by introducing a new variable for that quotient.
